Git push permission denied even after changing username
I am encountering permission denied errors when trying to push changes to a GitHub repository, even after updating the Git configuration with the correct username. The error message persists, stating: "Permission denied to VIJAYANAARAAYANAN."
Background:
I have a GitHub repository named Netflix-clone associated with the GitHub account VijayNaaraayanan.
Initially, I was pushing changes using the wrong username (VIJAYANAARAAYANAN). Then, I updated the global Git configuration with the correct username (VijayNaaraayanan).
Steps Taken:
git config --global user.name
The output confirmed that the username is set correctly to VijayNaaraayanan.
git credential-cache exit
git credential-manager erase
git push -u origin main
Expected Result:
I expect the changes to be pushed to the GitHub repository associated with the correct username (VijayNaaraayanan).
Actual Result:
I'm still encountering the "Permission denied to VIJAYANAARAAYANAN" error, preventing me from pushing the changes to the repository.
Additional Information:
I'm using Git Bash on Windows.
The repository URL is correct.
I have generated a personal access token and used it as the password during the push operation.
I have also tried switching to SSH authentication, but the issue persists.
Question:
How can I resolve this permission denied error and successfully push my changes to the GitHub repository associated with the correct username (VijayNaaraayanan)?

On Windows your Git credentials might be stored in Windows' own credential manager, did you check there too? That's where I had to clear my Git credentials at some point in the past.

How exactly did you switch to SSH authentication? What exact command did you use, and what was the exact output? (Note that I keep saying "exact" - this is not the place to hide details.)

Also - and I find myself saying this a lot around here - the user.name and user.email have NOTHING to do with authentication. You can change those every time you push and it will not make any difference. (I would like it if those parameters were renamed to author.name and author.email but I don't see that happening any time soon.)
